# I made an app that embeds a website in it. How to make any video in it able to be in full screen mode?

Tags: android, android-webview

I want an app that embeds a website in it but I can't make the videos in it full screen and how to put an adblock extension on this embedded website.

Comment: Hello Omar, welcome to SO. This question in this format will not receive much attention and definitely not receive good answers. Asking on SO needs a bit more work on your part: what have you tried so far? What exactly are you asking for? Can you show snippets of your code? Please spend a few minutes here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking to see how can you improve on this question - otherwise it will get downvoted and not answered. I would especially recommend this help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thank you I will update my question.